# I tried to use the syntax $inf_ to get value for checkut attributes

Tags: jquery, sql, attributes, word-wrap, var

I am getting the value but the problem is that the value gets wrapped in span tag.

For example 2 get the subtotl,
I used `var subtotal=$inf_cartAmt(chkCartSubtlAmt);`
Output for above syntax is

```
var subtotal=<span class="cartAmt_chkCartSubtlAmt">
$94.93
</span>;
```

Note how the val $94.93 is wrapped in span tag.
Do we have any other syntax which can just give the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what `$inf_cartAmt` is from your code, but you could try -

```
$inf_cartAmt(chkCartSubtlAmt).text();
```

Failing that, you could use jQuery to remove the span tag from your string -

```
subtotal = $(subtotal).text()
```